# Wordpress blog not showing in google/bing/yahoo

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Recently,I built my self hosted blog on wordpress http://shoutpanda.com & added some plugins like yoast SEo but when i searched in google with my domain name,It doesn't shows the blog.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be as specific as possible with your question. Include configuration, code, screen shots and etc. and what you exactly tried so far. You could add the "seo" tag for attention, too.

Comment: How recently did you upload the website to the domain?